# custom spacing for chapter page, and page number for normal page

Tags: spacing, chapters, page-numbering, geometry

I am trying to get the following geometry. I have geometry set like this: `\usepackage[a4paper, top=4cm,bottom=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,left=4cm, headheight=15pt]{geometry}` and I am using the book document class. I have been looking for some ideas on how to set a specific number of lines before and after the chapter's name (see figure 1), but without success. I am also required to have the page number 1.5cm above the first line of the text (see figure 2), but I do not know how to control it. Chapter page does not require page number, but others page do. Any help will be very much appreciated.

Figure1:

[image]

FIgure2:

[image]

**EDIT:**
Some more details, all I have been specified is to have a 4cm top and left margin, and a 2.5cm bottom and right margin. That is why I used the geometry package as indicated above. The pagenumber has to be at the top right of the page. Also, I am using a 12pt font size and Times New Roman and XeLatex. For the chapter name I am using the `\large` size.

Comment: please can you add a complete example? and what does mean top margin ?

Comment: @touhami Sorry for messing things up. I hope it is clear now. My understanding is that top margin is where the text starts, if no header is present, but I am not completely sure.

Comment: *A priori*, this can be done with `titlesec`, but we need more details.

Comment: @Bernard What kind of details? so I can add them.

Comment: The value for top margin (and also inner margin,  outer margin, text height, text width, paper format).  Where you want the page number exactly is not clear . Font size for chapter title and  for chapter label.

Comment: You can start out by including the package layout with `\usepackage{layout}` and then put `\layout` somewhere after `\begin{document}`. This will give you a picture of the page layout of your documents. Most importantly, it will show you where the various lengths are applied.

Comment: Which font size do you use for the document?

Comment: @Bernard I have added some more details, unfortunately I am unable to provide you details about outer and inner margin, as well as text width and height, since I have not been specified those parameters.

Comment: With the parameters for geometry, we have them: I suppose it will be a two sided document, and the `inner margin` is the   left margin  in this case, the `outer margin` is the  right margin. Note that for a good typography, the inner margin is more or less 1/2 outer margin (because, when you open a book you see 2 inner margins next to each other).  For the page number, this means it will appear  in the header, on the right if I understand well. Will there be page numbers on the first page of chapters?

Comment: @Bernard I actually need a one sided document. What I need is a 4cm from the top edge of the page to start the text, which I thought could be done by setting `top=4cm` in the geometry package. So if I need the page number to be at 1.5cm above the first line, it means I need to have it at 2.5cm from the top edge. There is no page number on the first page of chapters.

Comment: Some other questions: the first line of unnumbered chapters must also begin at 4cm of the top edge of the physical page? Which font size for the titles? And finally, do you know that double spacing is *not* singlespacing × 2, but more or less × 1.65, depending on the font size.

Comment: you can try `\usepackage[a4paper, top=4cm, bottom=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, left=4cm, headheight=15pt, headsep=1.5cm]{geometry}`

Comment: @Bernard Yes, the first line should also begin at 4cm from the top edge (this is the top margin in the pictures). Though for the first page of chapters (where the chapter name and number go, see  picture 1), there are 5 empty lines and then goes the chapter number, followed by the chapter name (this are in `\large` size). I was not aware of doublespacing being 1.65 times singlespacing, but what I need is the equivalent of double line spacing as in Word Office.

Comment: I've posted a solution. Would check if there's whatever to change. I had to guess the font size. Also, note the interline spacing   depends on the actual font size. This implies that for titles, as the font size is bigger, the interline spacing will be bigger. I didn't which font size you need for chapter titles, so I chose somewhat arbitrarily, `\Large`,, i.e., 17.28pt for a document in 12pt). You didn't neither if the title had to be centred, nor if you want a header  rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I understood of your requirements:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{book}%
\usepackage[top=4cm,bottom=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,left=4cm, headheight=15pt, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{lipsum,setspace }
\usepackage[pagestyles, clearempty]{titlesec}

\newpagestyle{myps}{%
\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{empty}
\sethead[\thepage][][]{}{}{\thepage}
\setfoot{}{}{}}%

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\Large\bfseries}{\chaptername~\thechapter}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{32pt}{28pt}%
\titlespacing*{name=\chapter, numberless}{0pt}{54pt}{28pt}%
\pagestyle{myps}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A first chapter}

\lipsum[1-6]

\chapter*{Test chapter}

\lipsum[2-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please explain how you came up with those number in the titlespacing? Also, is there a way to get  rid of the header in the first page of chapters?

Comment: My pdfviewer has a measurement tool, so I measured the actual value of interline spacing on the basis of the distance between the first and  the 10th line of normal text. This gave with  a good precision, a value of 13pt. Then I found the values in \titlespacing by trial and errors. Of course, if you change the font size, you have to do it all again, but you have an order of magnitude. For your second question, you don't have a header on the first page of chapters: it is the `showframe` option of geometry, for checking. Delete it for the final version, of course.

Comment: May I know what that pdfviewer is?

Comment: SumatraPDF (under Windows). But GSview also has this possibility.